# Ubuntu 22.04 asks for password or encryption key to connect wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, encryption

I entered the password correctly. I have the connection but it breaks after some amount of seconds/minutes - randomly. I can reconnect but it keeps breaking.

I attach the settings on screenshots below:

[image: Details]
[image: Security]

$ iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"*****"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: *****   
          Bit Rate=108 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:23   Missed beacon:0

docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: 26Mb/s points to quite weak signal. Can you [edit] your question to include the output of the command `iwconfig`?

Comment: And it's a dual band router improperly configured with the same name (SSID) to both band. It should always be set as 2 different access points.

Comment: I also have a connection to the 5GHz bandwidth (I haven't tried it though). But in the description, it has the same supported frequencies (2.4 GHz / 5 GHz). Do you mean, the problem lies in both the connections not having separate supported frequencies?